# What is the difference between American and British pronunciations of "world" and "girl"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, differences, british-english

I can definitely hear a distinct difference but I am not sure if it is from the long vowel or from the "r".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a definite difference in the /r/; see this on [rhotic and non-rhotic accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents) where rhotic accents are typical in most of America but not in England outside the south-west.  So for *[girl](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/girl)* (/ɡɝl/ and /ɡɜːl/) and *[world](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/world)* (/wɝld/ and /wɜː(ɹ)ld/) the /r/ is almost not pronounced in non-rhotic accents, though the vowels are similar in both accents.

Comment: I'm not sure what phonetically you mean by "almost" not pronounced. If you have evidence of some kind of residual pronunciation of an /r/ in "non-rhotic" accents, then this would be a very interesting finding, but unless you're putting such evidence forward, I think it's safer to assume that there is no /r/ in non-rhotic accents.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: You are probably right.  I am used to various Irish and Shropshire relations who change register and become less rhotic and more London RP as they become more careful in their speech; it sounds to me more of a fading away than a shift - so much so that I cannot tell when it has gone.

Comment: The vowels are ***not*** the same in both accents. The American vowel is usually either the consonant [/ɹ/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_approximant) used as a vowel, or the "bunched r", which is an r-colored vowel that sounds almost exactly the same. In particular, I don't believe many Americans actually follow a vowel with an 'r' in /ɝ/ (with other vowels, following them with an [ɹ] is quite common).